# set div to none display java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

im working on mvc asp , i have very simple div i want to hide them , the problem is it hide it but it show it again why that is happened ???
this my code  plz watch the video to know what im talking about 
https://www.useloom.com/share/52a0bc2703294bb58f475ae40bcc7d4b

```js
        $("#myHref").on('click', function () {
            document.getElementById("PatientEdit").style.display = "none";
            var y = document.getElementById("UsersList");
            var z = document.getElementById("UsersEdit");
           
            y.style.display = "none";
            z.style.display = "none";
            console.log("Hello world!");
           //alert("inside onclick menu.js ");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <a href="http://localhost:65043/Patients" id="myHref">Patiens</a>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="PatientEdit">PatientEdit</div>
        <div id="UsersList">UsersList</div>
        <div id="UsersEdit">UsersEdit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: On button click you are redirecting page which is causing this to reappear again. You need to handle this on page load as well.

Comment: yes u r right i fixed it ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok so what you need to change is this part `<a href="#0" id="myHref">Patiens</a>`
Your link `<a href="http://localhost:65043/Patients" id="myHref">Patiens</a>` is redirecting and loading the page all over again.

```js
$("#myHref").on('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("PatientEdit").style.display = "none";
  var y = document.getElementById("UsersList");
  var z = document.getElementById("UsersEdit");

  y.style.display = "none";
  z.style.display = "none";
  console.log("Hello world!");
  //alert("inside onclick menu.js ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#0" id="myHref">Patiens</a>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="PatientEdit">PatientEdit</div>
  <div id="UsersList">UsersList</div>
  <div id="UsersEdit">UsersEdit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$(this).find("#PatientEdit").css("visibility", "hidden");
$(this).find("#PatientEdit").css("visibility", "visible");`

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if you’ve already tried this, but if not, perhaps this may work?

```
$(“#PatientEdit”).hide();
$(“#UsersList”).hide();
$(“#UsersEdit”).hide();
```

Comment: no the result is the same thanks for trying , my code also work the same way it display the divs then it will show again

Comment: When does it show again? When you refresh the page?

Comment: take care because you're not using the correct quotes and it will throw an error. `“` != `"` @AngelGarcia

Comment: That is true ^ sorry I’m typing this answer on my phone. Calvin Nunes is absolutely correct.

Comment: its ok i realized that no worries